# Testing file upload with Capybara - not a form but button and javascript function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rspec, capybara

I am struggling to get that test working, tested several approaches and nothing works so far. 
I have a button

```
<div >
  <a href class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg btn-shadowed ut-upload-button"
    ng-file-select
    ng-file-change="uplFile($event, $file)">
    <i class="icon">i</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

this is a button that when clicked opens OS file browser, anyone knows how to get that to work as I tried attach_file, page.attach_file,
find(".ut-upload-button").set(Rails.root + 'spec/files/file.txt')

Once uploaded the page should display a toast Success

```
expect(page).to have_toast('Success')
```

Sorry if it is a basic mistake or silly question, I am just starting using rspec and capybara and got lost completely

Comment: The `ng-file-select` directive is not a core AngularJS directive. Hard to help without the code for that directive.

Comment: You need to look at the actual HTML generated for the page (open page in a browser and inspect it).  The angular library you're using has to have added an `<input type='file'>` element somewhere to the page in order to make file upload work - that's what you need to attach the file to.  I've also updated my answer with code you can try if there is only one file uploader on the page.

Answer (score 12):

You can't do that because once the system file browser opens there is no way for the driver to interact with it.  You need to call `attach_file` for the actual <input type='file'> element (which in your case is probably hidden on the page). Since you don't show your HTML I can't provide the exact code - but assuming you have an element something like the following

```
<input type='file' name='file_upload'>
```

and that the input is hidden from view via CSS of some type then something like

```
page.attach_file('file_upload', Rails.root + 'spec/files/file.txt', make_visible: true)
```

should work for you.  If there is only one file upload on the page you could also do

```
page.attach_file(Rails.root + 'spec/files/file.txt', make_visible: true)
```

If you're willing to try the master branch of the Capybara project, it currently has trial support for passing a block to `attach_file` that opens the file selector.  In your case that would probably be something like

```
page.attach_file(Rails.root + 'spec/files/file.txt') do
  page.find(".ut-upload-button").click
end
```

The feature is there for user testing and may or may not make it into Capybara 3.15 (depending on how well it is reported to work with the many many many ways there are to style file inputs) when it's released in a month or so.

Comment: Thank you very much. It turned out that we are using a very outdated capybara and there is a bug that doe snot allow for file upload.

Answer (score 1):

1. This works on windows or Linux

   - `filename = '/features/pages/images/imagetest01.jpg'`
   - `file = File.join(Dir.pwd, filename)`
   - `find('input#nameIDinput', :visible => false).send_keys file`

Comment: Please only post in English on Stack Overflow. Thanks.

Comment: This will probably only work with Chrome and should only be considered if you’re sure you never want to test with a different browser. You’d be much better off reading the Capybara docs for `attach_file` and using the relevant options for your pages usage of file inputs